# Remote Debugging Azure Worker Role

Tags: azure, remote-debugging, azure-worker-roles

There are a million links like this one http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cie/archive/2014/01/24/windows-azure-remote-debugging.aspx, which more or less would seem to take care of the remote debugging setup. I have done this many times in VS 2013 Update 2, deployed, then attached to debugger and it simply does not work. Well, the debugger seems to attach, but I continually get the message when I hover over a break point informing me that 'The breakpoint will currently not be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document' A while back I recall seeing a channel 9 presentation and they seemed to configre the symbol store. I tried configuring this and it still gives me the same message when hovering over the breakpoint.

Comment: Hey @Mike W, I'm having the same issue with debugging Azure Websites. I'll try deploying a 'Debug' build to see if that eases the pain but the docs don't require a debug build and seem to imply it will work with a 'Release' build if you disable the option for 'Enable Just My Code'.

Comment: Try to connect to your instance and check if the .pdb files are in the folder. Maybe they are not deployed with your package. You can test your package before deployment too - just unzip it and check for the pdb files. There can be no symbol store for your assemblies because their symbols come from your machine.

Answer (score 6):

VS 2013 Update 2 Remote Debugging - I can only get it to work with a 'Debug' build. I have set the Debugging Option "Enable Just My Code" and loaded all symbols -- this seems to work fine. I can now set breakpoints and do not receive the message you (and I) noted earlier.

This is probably not the ideal situation as it would be nice to be able to attach the debugger to a production release but it seems to be a semi-reasonable workaround for now.

**EDIT:**
Important points:

1. You must enable Remote Debugging in the Azure Portal for your Cloud Service or Web Site -- *Configure* Tab (it only remains enabled for 48 Hours)
2. The *debug* attribute of the *compilation* element in your *Web.config* file must be set to "true". This means, you either have to do a 'Debug' build or manually edit the *Web.config* file. Here is a link to official Microsoft documentation with a full explanation and a great example of how to do that without redeploying your application:
   http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-dotnet-troubleshoot-visual-studio/#remotedebug
3. If you still have problems you may have to disable the Debugging Option *Enable Just My Code* in Visual Studio

Comment: Be sure to add your IP Address to the firewall rules while you are debugging remotely.

Comment: Here's another reference specifically for Cloud Services and Virtual Machines: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff683670.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem - also with VS 2013 Update 2.

The crucial bit I missed was selecting the *w3wp.exe* process in the pop-up that shows the running processes before hitting the Attach button.